# Using passport-facebook without Mongoose User (No Mongo in the MEAN stack)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, passport-facebook

I'm very new to the MEAN stack, and this might seem to be very naive or wrong approach, but I want to ask that when we authenticate using passport-facebook strategy, using the following code:

```
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
var User = require('../models/user');
var fbConfig = require('../fb.js');

module.exports = function(passport) {

passport.use('facebook', new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID        : fbConfig.appID,
    clientSecret    : fbConfig.appSecret,
    callbackURL     : fbConfig.callbackUrl
},

// facebook will send back the tokens and profile
function(access_token, refresh_token, profile, done) {

    console.log('profile', profile);

    // asynchronous
    process.nextTick(function() {

        // find the user in the database based on their facebook id
        User.findOne({ 'id' : profile.id }, function(err, user) {

            // if there is an error, stop everything and return that
            // ie an error connecting to the database
            if (err)
                return done(err);

            // if the user is found, then log them in
            if (user) {
                return done(null, user); // user found, return that user
            } else {
                // if there is no user found with that facebook id, create them
                var newUser = new User();

                // set all of the facebook information in our user model
                newUser.fb.id    = profile.id; // set the users facebook id                 
                newUser.fb.access_token = access_token; // we will save the token that facebook provides to the user                    
                newUser.fb.firstName  = profile.name.givenName;
                newUser.fb.lastName = profile.name.familyName; // look at the passport user profile to see how names are returned
                //newUser.fb.email = profile.emails[0].value; // facebook can return multiple emails so we'll take the first

                // save our user to the database
                newUser.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        throw err;

                    // if successful, return the new user
                    return done(null, newUser);
                });
            }

        });
    });

}));

};
```

I don't need to store the user information in any data store. I want to store the token only for the time the user is logged into my web application, basically I don't have the need to use Mongo, because all the data that will be displayed in the web application will come from Facebook api, for example the posts for a profile, the number of likes on a particular posts etc. I don't need to have a backend as such, because if I store the data in any data store such as Mongo, the next time the user login then the data will be stale (in a way the Facebook api is kind of my backend), and I also want that the updates for information on any posts done on Facebook should be updated realtime on my web application for e.g. if someone likes a post on the actual Facebook page the number of likes on my web application should also be updated in realtime, so it seems unnecessary to first bring the data from the Facebook SDK and then store it in Mongo, why not just give it to the controller and from there the view can present the data. If my approach is wrong please do correct me.

So basically every time the user logs in an access token is created and used for that session, when the user logs out the access token is destroyed and so completely eliminates the need for storing the token and any data that is brought in using the Facebook SDK.

Comment: What I was thinking of was to use basically angular models for handling the data thats coming in from the Facebook SDK and then the controller can do its job in conjunction with the Views.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the function call

```
 User.findOne({ 'id' : profile.id }, function(err, user) {
```

With facebook sdk authentication call and return the user object when it's validated.

```
  return done(null, user);
```

Please refer...

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook

Comment: I want to confirm is my approach correct for bringing the data from the Facebook SDK, not storing the data in the Mongo and ingesting the data directly from the Facebook SDK and how do I use angular models for storing the data.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a new user template in the model folder. I have created the following: user.js

```
var  facebook =  module.exports.facebook =       {
    id           : String,
    token        : String,
    email        : String,
    name         : String
}
```

and then change the passport.serializeUser and passport.deserializeUser functions.

```
  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.facebook.id);
    });

    // used to deserialize the user
    //passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        done(null, { id: User.facebook.id, token: User.facebook.token, name: User.facebook.name, email: User.facebook.email})

    });
```

then the function:  process.nextTick(function() {} replace the content by this code :

```
var newUser = User;
                    // set all of the facebook information in our user model
                    newUser.facebook.id    = profile.id; // set the users facebook id                   
                    newUser.facebook.token = token; // we will save the token that facebook provides to the user                    
                    newUser.facebook.name  = profile.name.givenName + ' ' + profile.name.familyName; // look at the passport user profile to see how names are returned
                    newUser.facebook.email = profile.emails[0].value; // facebook can return multiple emails so we'll take the first

                    return done(null, newUser);
```

add the line `profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'photos', 'emails', 'name']` in function `passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({}`

change the profile.ejs file by removing the local information div and changing the properties `<% = user.facebook.id%> to <% = user.id%>` and so on in the others.